# Why is there no qmake-qt5 included in the qt5-default package

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qmake, odroid

I installed qt5-default on my Odroid XU3 using the the `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` command and wanted to run qmake-qt5 using the terminal but it printed that this command is unknown. Then I looked in the usr/share/qt5 folder and noticed that there is only the doc-foder inside. I also looked in the usr/bin folder and could only find qmake-qt4 but no qmake-qt5. When I run the install command, I also read that some libraries will be installed, so I think, libraries are not the problem.

Next I tried to install qmake-q5t manually from this page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/qt5-qmake but then I got a message that there is a newer version of qmake-qt5 already installed. I searched the whole system using the find command for qmake-qt5 but couldn't detect it.

Last I also tried to add the ubuntu-sdk ppa using as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/279421/how-can-i-install-qt-5-x-on-12-04-lts but this also didn't work out.

Does it have something to do with my Odroid or with Lubuntu? Is there any other way to install qmake-qt5?

I tried to compile and make with the already installed qt4 and this did work out using

```
qmake-qt4 -project
qmake-qt4
make
./helloworld
```

I want do the same but only with qt5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The qmake executable is installed in `/usr/lib/<your_arch>/qt5/bin` as `qmake` (no `-qt5` suffix).

You can check with `qmake --version`, it should report you a Qt version 5.x.x